# I have no sound - "No output or input devices found"

Tags: debian, audio

Running Debian Bullseye on an Acer Aspire 5 I have no sound - "No output or input devices found"

Available controllers revealed by `lspci` are as follows:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Anyone else with this problem, or a solution will be welcomed to my Christmas card list.

I suspect an absence of drivers, but would welcome any help.

Comment: I have note personally checked Debian Bullseye but I know a lot of Debian release do not have the non free / proprietary repos enabled by default.  Usually they offer a version with and one without the non free firmware do you know which one you have.  https://www.xmodulo.com/install-nonfree-packages-debian.html This is a quick link I found showing how to check and also how to enable non free you will have to change the release names to fit your situation.

Comment: Yes. I know about non-free and installed the drivers. With Bullseye and this Acer m/c it wasn't a solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from buster to bullseye as per docs with

```
apt full-upgrade
```

these packages were missing for me on bullseye.

```
aptitude install pulseaudio gnome-control-center
```